# Why findLoadedClass method call is required in loadClass method?

Tags: java

As I was doing some experiment on class loading I wrote simple code like below.

```
    CustomClass customClass1 = new CustomClass();
    CustomClass customClass2 = new CustomClass();
```

And noticed that for the first instance creation it went to loadClass method and called the findLoadedClass method if it is already loaded by the current loader. It was not so it went ahead and loaded the class.
But for second instance it did not go to loadClass method and directly created the instance of that.

So my question here is, when it was creating the second instance it already new that the class is already loaded so it did not go to loadClass method. So when jvm already now that which class is loaded and which is not then what is the need findLoadedClass method call inside loadClass method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Java Virtual Machine Specification (for Java 8), section 5.3.2:

> The following steps are used to load and thereby create the nonarray class or interface C denoted by N using a user-defined class loader L.
>
> First, the Java Virtual Machine determines whether L has already been recorded as an initiating loader of a class or interface denoted by N. If so, this class or interface is C, and no class creation is necessary.
>
> Otherwise, the Java Virtual Machine invokes loadClass(N) on L. The value returned by the invocation is the created class or interface C. The Java Virtual Machine then records that L is an initiating loader of C (§5.3.4).

This explains why `loadClass` is not called again in your example. But it doesn't mean that `loadClass` will never be called on this particular classloader for this particular class' fqn. It may happen for example due to classloading delegation, when some other classloader acts as the initiating classloader, but delegates the call to its `loadClass` to this classloader's `loadClass`. Hence the call to `findLoadedClass`.